# Limit with brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I would need to verify if this answer is correct. Thanks in advance for the help.

Given $B_t$, $t \geq 0$ a brownian motion, determine

$
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t} P[\max_{s \in [0,t]} \{B_s\} \leq 1]    
$

Where P stands for probability.

This is what i did:

$
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t} P[\max_{s \in [0,t]} \{B_s\} \leq 1] = 
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t} [1-2P[B_t \geq 1]] 
$
by application of the reflection principle. Now

$
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t} [1-2P[B_t \geq 1]] =
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t} [2P[B_t < 1] - 1] =
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t} [2\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}) - 1] 
$

where $\Phi$ stands for the standard normal probability distribution. This is a $0 \times \infty$ indetermination since $\Phi(0)=1/2$. 
Applying l'hopital rule,

$
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{[2\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})-1]}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}} =
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\Pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2t}) dx -1 \right]}{\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right]} = 
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\Pi}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2t^2}) {\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right]}}{\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right]} = 
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\Pi}}
$

Is this correct?
Many thanks.

Comment: The integral in the last line should be of $\exp(-x^2/2)$, not $\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2t})$. Everything else looks correct to me.